# How to remove "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php" completely from my Laravel 8 project

Tags: algolia, laravel-8

I have already removed [algolia/algoliasearch-client-php](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php) package by using the `composer remove` command from my Laravel 8 project, but I am still getting below error while calling `delete()`, `redirect()`.

Please help me to fix the below error.

> Exception Please install the Algolia client:
> algolia/algoliasearch-client-php.

In the composer.lock file; We have below the message. It can create problem plz confirm also:

"suggest": {
"algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "Required to use the Algolia engine (^2.2)."
}

Answer (score 3):

If you are not going to be using algolia anymore then you don't need scout most likely. Your models are still setup to use scout which will still be looking for the algolia drivers.

Perhaps you want to remove `Searchable` from your Models if you are not planning on using any of these services for search indexing.

Comment: Very thanks @lagbox ..I have find the search keyword in my project but it's not using anywhere now. But I am getting above error when i called "$thread->delete();"..plz help to fix .

Comment: @Dhiru see if your `Thread` model is using the `Searchable` trait

Comment: Very thanks for your reply @lagbox, I have removed searchable keyword & also removed "composer remove laravel/scout". After that my issue have resolved